# prevent cell reference from iterating when dragging marque down column

Tags: excel, function, loops

I have a cell, B2000, with a constant value in it, namely *5.25*. I reference that value in cell H5 via a function `=B2000+G5`.

Now I want to highlight cell H5, and then drag the marque down, such that the reference to B2000 will not iterate, but the reference to G5 will iterate down the column.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=$B$2000+G5`.

Just use absolute references for `B2000`.

The `$` creates an absolute reference:

`$B2000` will let you drag the formula right and left (i.e. change columns) without the reference to `B`column changing.

`B$2000` lets you drag the formula down, without changing the row.  ...therefore `$B$2000` lets you drag/copy the formula and the reference won't change.